# WebDav Server library preferably in Java

Tags: java, api, webdav

I have an app used to manage files and folders that exposes services through an homemade RESTFul Api and I would like to add Webdav features so that files that I host can be easily accessed through standard file explorers or directly modified via MS Office and related software.

I'm looking for a server Webdav library preferably in Java to build a really simple application that would be a bridge between incoming Webdav request and my Api. Main requirement is that the Api has to support Webdav level 2 features (locking).

I have tried the Milton Api once in the past but they have changed their licensing to AGPL3 and I don't want to make my whole application AGPL3 nor can afford the commercial license so I'm looking for other alternatives.

What Api do you use or recommend?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not tied to java you could use SabreDav (PHP).

Just clarifying milton's licensing (was changed recently) all the DAV level 1 features are available in an apache2 licensed jar which is all you need for the use cases mentioned in the question.

The AGPL+commercial license applies to the extension jar which provides locking, calendar and contacts.

Cheers,
Brad

Comment: I thought that DAV level 2 features (locking especially) were required to open documents via MS Office. Is it wrong? If I can open and edit via MS Office with the standard apache2 licensed version then I will go for this solution (I have already played with it last year and really liked its ease of use).

Answer (score 0):

Milton is using the Apache 2 license: https://github.com/miltonio/milton2/blob/master/LICENSE.txt

Only the enterprise extensions use AGPL.

---

From the homepage:

Milton.io is a Java Webdav Server Library supporting Webdav level 2, CalDav, CardDav.

Integrate your java web app with desktop and mobile devices for files, calendars and contacts

Your data could be relational databases, file system, web services or any other data source

Supports Windows, Mac, Linux, Android and iOS devices, and pretty much everything else.